# Segmentation fault occurs when generating large amounts of doubles with rand() in C

Tags: c, random, floating-point, segmentation-fault, double

According to *gdb* this line causes a segmentation fault

```
((double) rand()/(double) (RAND_MAX)) * (r*2)
```

but this is completely fine

```
((float) rand()/(float) (RAND_MAX)) * (r*2)
```

I can make do with floats, but this bugs me. Am I doing something wrong or is `rand()` incapable of dealing with doubles.

Notice that in the context of upper example all occurrences of `float` were changed to `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct cord {
    /* float or double */
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    float r = 3.0;
    int amount = 1000000;
    struct cord cords[amount];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        cords[i] = (struct cord) {
            /* Segfault occurs when (float) is replaced with (double) */
            ((float) rand()/(float) (RAND_MAX)) * (r*2),
            ((float) rand()/(float) (RAND_MAX)) * (r*2)
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared a huge array on the stack, which results in a stack overflow. Declare `cords` as `static`, or move it outside of the function.

Comment: Are `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(double)` different? What are the values?

Comment: Typically using `double` struct members will need twice the stack as `float` members. Perhaps there is enough stack for `float` members but not `double`.

Comment: One million of the `float` structure requires just under 8 MiB of stack; that's the default stack limit on many Unix systems, and considerably bigger than the default stack limit on Windows systems.  When you try to allocate 16 MiB on the stack instead (using `double`), your code crashes.  Don't allocate the space on the stack.  Move it into static memory (you'll have to go from using a VLA — variable length array — to a constant array dimension) or use dynamic memory allocation.  There are multiple other questions which manifest the same problem (allocating too much data on the stack).

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe an alignment issue. We need to see the real code and the exact line of the error. The compiler may be able to diagnose it with `-Wcast-align`. Otherwise, the Undefined Behavior sanitizer can probably tell you where the misaligned read or write is occurring.

Comment: You got a stack overflow! Your stack is probably full, and the next double would put it at a lower memory address hence the segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time the segfault occurs, **there is no more stack space** to allocate the new `double` value. The location of the next double would be at an illegal (out-of-bounds) memory address, hence the segfault.

The reason why your code does not segfault for `float` is because floats are single-precision and usually requires **half the number of bytes (usually 4B)** to store compared to a double (usually 8B). Your code still have sufficient space to store all the floats.